# Criar thumbnail a partir de um upload multiplo

Tags: php, upload, imagem, thumbnail

Boa tarde, já pesquisei e tentei varias opcoes e nao consegui.

Estou tentando fazer um upload de imagens multiplas, e cada imagem gerar uma thumbnail e registrar apenas as imagens originais no banco de dados. Porém gera a thumb de apenas uma imagem ou cria uma imagem com todos os nomes dos arquivos do upload, isso se da quando eu troco `$novaImagem` por `$img` por exemplo:

```
tbn_1231455.jpg,tbn_3244545.jpg,tbn_8748545.jpg
```

Estou precisando de ajuda, segue abaixo o meu codigo.

```
if (isset($_FILES['imagemlocal']))
{       
   $largura = 1024;
   $altura = 1024;
   $tamanho =  200000;
   $tmp = $_FILES['imagemlocal'];
   list($largura,$altura,$tip)=getimagesize($tmp);
   $dimensoes = getimagesize($imagemlocal["tmp_name"]);

   $img = array();
   for ($key = 0; $key < count($tmp['name']); $key++) {
      $path = $_FILES['imagemlocal']['name'][$key];
      $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      $temp_name = $_FILES['imagemlocal']['tmp_name'][$key];
      $novaImagem = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext;
      $caminho = 'img/'.$novaImagem;
      move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $caminho);
      $img[] = ("$novaImagem");
   }
   $img = implode(', ', $img);          
}

//thumb

if($tip > 1) {
   $percent = 0.15;
   $new_largura = $largura * $percent;
   $new_altura = $altura * $percent;

   $thundebal = imagecreatefromjpeg($caminho);
}
else {
   $thundebal = imagecreatefrompng($caminho);
}

$Thundeball = imagecreatetruecolor($new_largura, $new_altura);
imagecopyresampled($Thundeball, $thundebal, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_largura, $new_altura, $largura, $altura);
if($tip > 1) {
    imagejpeg($Thundeball,"img/".'/tbn_'.$novaImagem);
}
else {
    imagepng($Thundeball,"img/".'/tbn_'.$novaImagem);
}
```

Comment: O código que gera o thumb precisa estar dentro do for

Comment: A variável: `$novaImagem` fora do for, será sempre a última da lista, você só vai gerar uma sempre. Tudo tem que estar dentro do loop de acordo com as quantidades.

Comment: Ivan Ferrer e caiocafardo, MUITÍSSIMO obrigado!!! Meu projeto estava parado. Funcionou perfeitamente!!!

Comment: @IvanFerrer eu mandei uma mensagem pelo teu site.